# What's the best RgEx (PHP) to handle nested <div> tags and properly insert code inside the outer most one?

Tags: php, html, regex

So I'm trying to write a simple HTML search and replace of content. I'm using  the following code with a WYSIWYG editor.. I tried various editors and they allow render code with .. When the PHP script sees code like the one below..

```
 <div class='editable' id="edit01" >Content inside div  to change. <div
```

It uses this command:

```
 $replacement ="<div class='editable' id="$id" >".$user_generated_content."</div>";      
$new_html= preg_replace('#(<div[^>]*id=[\'|"]'.$id.'[\'|"][^>]*>)(.*)</div>#isU', $replacement , $page_html);
```

The issue occurs when teh user generated content contains nested **div** tags, the regex then improperly replaces the code, because it considers the first ending

```
</div>
```

as a match and it places the replacement in the wrong spot.
So I'm asking how can I enforce PHP Regex to just search for the outermost div tags?

Comment: `"<div class='editable' id="$id" >" ...` will throw a syntax error after parsing the string `<div class='editable' id=`. Having said that, you'd be better off using a parser to accomplish this.

Comment: Since the user generated content is being inserted into the `page_html`, whether it has `<div>` elements in it shouldn't matter. Perhaps I'm not understanding your question properly? If you could provide samples for `$user_generated_content` and `$page_html` and what you expect the value of `$new_html` to be it would be easier to understand where your problem is.